# How to add multi column data using Bash

Tags: bash, awk

I have a bash file say input.dat which looks like following.

```
1   2   4   6
2   3   6   9
3   4   8   12
```

I want the data in 2nd, 3rd and 4th column to be added and printed in output.dat file like following

```
1   12
2   18
3   24
```

How can this be achieved in bash ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using awk you can do this:

```
 awk '{print $1, $2+$3+$4}' input.dat
```

and if you prefer bash it can be done like this (at least if the numbers are integers): `bash sum.sh <  input.dat` and sum.sh is

**sum.sh**

```
while read -r v1 v2 v3 v4;
do
    echo $v1 $(( v2 + v3 + v4 ))
done
```

Comment: Thank you :) that helped